# distutils: how to include test files in source distribution and not in build?

Tags: python, distutils

I have a simple, pure python project that I want to make available with distutils. I have successfully created compressed tar files for the python modules and some license text files. These are the relevant parts of the `setup.py` `setup` argument list:

```
  packages=['pkgA',
            'pkgA.subpkgA1',
            'pkgA.subpkgA2'],
  requires = ['matplotlib', 'pytest'],
  data_files = [ 'COPYING', 'COPYING.LESSER'],
```

The only problem is that this also puts the license files in the distribution, directly under `sys.prefix`. I would like to ship the license files in the source distribution, but not install them when `python setup.py install` is run. I currently have no `MANIFEST.in` file and no post build actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to put anything in data_files.  The arguments to distutils.core.setup (py_modules, packages, data_files, etc.) control what will be built and installed; to distribute additional file, use a MANIFEST.in file: http://docs.python.org/dev/distutils/sourcedist#specifying-the-files-to-distribute  There you can have your COPYING file, Python files for tests, anything, and they will not be installed.